# Cannot export docx which contains html paragraph tag via PHPWord library

Tags: php, laravel, phpword

I'm using this [library](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)

Code example:

```
<?php

use \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;

$phpWord = new PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$section->addText('test');
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('Appdividend.docx');
return response()->download(public_path('Appdividend.docx'));
```

It works fine and returns docx file with "test" text, but when replace this row :

`$section->addText('test');` with this one

`$section->addText('<p>test</p>');` the docx document is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just write the HTML formatted text into a DOCX field.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).